# Access menu-settings when translating a content without edit permission

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

What permission is appropriate to access "menu settings" when translating a page of a content where edit permission is prohibited.
The role itself has the permission to create and edit own content but not of others and in that case "menu settings" isn't shown at translate.

And after saving a translation the original menu entry is set inactive/deletet as well. maybe a bug as well?!

Answer (score 0):

The permission you need is `Administer menus and menu items`:

[image]

About your second question, I have tested on a fresh D8 install but can't reproduce it. You should check if any custom logic is interfering with that flow.